# accessing a samba mapped drive from terminal

Tags: samba

I have mapped a samba share from the GUI (12.04) of my desktop and it works fine, but I would like to connect to this machine (the one I mapped from) via ssh and be able to see the mapped share.  However, looking at /dev etc. I don't see anything like it.  It appears in the Nautilus display just fine, I can read and write, but only from the GUI,not from the terminal display.  What am I missing?  I mapped from the GUI so it seems I don't get to specify a mount point.

Comment: check `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. There is a mount point in there ([share name] and path)

Comment: How about `mount|grep cifs` to see all the mounted shares and the destination on which they were mounted?

Comment: Getting closer I think but /etc/samba/smb.conf contains only persistent mounts.  The mount command (without cifs) shows the list of mounts, in /run/user/[user]/gvfs it shows the mapping parameters, as: smb-share:domain=AMS,server=ams-fs07,share=marketing,user=administrator, but I can't seem to extract anything that an ls or cp would work with.

Comment: I want to sort of wrap this up by saying that I really don't have the solution I was looking for, although I appreciate the answers I did get, which anyway taught me some things I didn't know. No matter where I look, I can find no record of the share in the file system. If I create another share at the command line, I can see that one, and maybe that's what I'll have to do, but using an existing GUI-created share -- for me, anyway -- just doesn't work. Strange, but so it is. Thanks to everyone, anyway. -- Jim

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed.... I'm having the same problem. I can access a work windows share via GUI, but how can I even ls files in the terminal? I have a huge amount of files in the windows share that I need to categorize and it would be much simpler with ls instead of nautilus... I'm suprised this isn't a common issue

Answer (score 1):

If a samba share is connected, you should be able to access it from Terminal simply by navigating to `.gvfs/` in your home folder.

Run `ls .gvfs/` to see what's in it.

Comment: Nothing there.  Connected in Gnome, but nothing in that directory.

Comment: Interesting. I just do `cd ".gvfs/mini on Inspiron/"`, and I am in the home folder on another machine. The following also works: `smbclient //server/share -U username`.